# Strongloop Loopback REST Query and/or combined with between

Tags: rest, strongloop, between, loopback

I have a simple model object with startDate and endDate properties.

I can not seem to query with both 'and/or' and 'between' using the REST api. I would like to query 'between' a startDate range 'or' an endDate range. I would have thought that the following query would have worked:

```
?filter[where][or][0][event.startDate][between][0]=2017-01-15&filter[where][or][0][event.startDate][between][1]=2017-01-22&filter[where][or][1][event.endDate][between][0]=2017-01-15&filter[where][or][1][event.endDate][between][1]=2017-01-22
```

Ideally I would have liked to query between event.startDate and event.endDate but loopback does not like the following query:

```
?filter[where][event.startDate][between][0]=2017-01-15&filter[where][event.endDate][between][1]=2017-01-22
```

The queries work independently just fine:

```
?filter[where][event.startDate][between][0]=2017-01-15&filter[where][event.startDate][between][1]=2017-01-22

?filter[where][event.endDate][between][0]=2017-01-15&filter[where][event.endDate][between][1]=2017-01-22
```

Here is my model definition:

---

models/event.json

```
{
  "name": "event",
  "plural": "events",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": false
    },
    "startDate": {
      "type": "date",
      "required": false
    },
    "endDate": {
      "type": "date",
      "required": false
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I could not make the REST query work in that case either.

Ultimately, we had to resort to building the query via stringified JSON, see the [docs](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Querying-data.html#using-stringified-json-in-rest-queries)

So, something like this

```js
let filter = {
  where: {
    or: [
      {
        'event.startDate': {
          between: ['2017-01-15', '2017-01-22']
        }
      },
      {
        'event.endDate': {
          between: ['2017-01-15', '2017-01-22']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};

let url = `/api?filter=${JSON.stringify(filter)}`;
```

It also made query building a lot simpler, actually.